# Assigning integer values to letters

Tags: c++

Is it possible to assign a integer value to an letter like 'A'?
For example, if  the user entered 'A', I want to display the value assigned to it (for example, 1). I am planning to assign a value to every letter in the alphabet.
I found out that you can do it with map library but I don't want to use any libraries. Is there a way to do it with only basic C++ stuff?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and then try to execute this code: `std::cout << static_cast<int>('A');`. Proceed with `'B'`, `'C'` and so on. Observe and learn that it's already done for you

Comment: Characters *are* integers. You could also use arrays, maps or any other kind of data structure you want. But for SO you need to present the code you have tried and explain what's wrong with it

Comment: And what is the reason that you don't want to use [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)? I mean the std was created to solve such things in a standardized way.

Comment: It's an assignment from school and we're only allowed to use standart libraries. I know every letter has an integer value assigned to them, for example A being 65 but it complicates thing for my situation. I can't share the code because its written in my native language and it would take forever to change it into english to make you understand...

Comment: Now you learnt why you should always write code and comments in English. Also as already mentioned `std::map` is part of the standard library

Comment: You always should mention if you ask questions about assignments, and that certain parts have the requirement to be solve it that way. And about the `we're only allowed to use standart libraries.` the `std` is part of the c++ standard, and [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is in the standard library and part of the c++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple way would be to associate a simple raw array by indexing:

```
char char_num_slots[] = { '\0' /* associates to index 0 */
                        , 'A' /* associates to index 1 */
                        , 'C' /* associates to index 2 */
                        , 'K' /* associates to index 3 */
                        // aso ...
                        };
```

The natural way to go in c++ would be using a [`std::map<char,int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) though:

```
std::map<char,int> char_num_slots = { { 'A', 1 }
                                    , { 'C', 42 }
                                    , { 'K', 512 }
                                    // aso ...
                                    };
```

I think it's obvious where the difference is in the above shown approaches, and how using `std::map` is superior.

> Is there a way to do it with only basic C++ stuff?

Yes, using `std::map` counts as c++ *basic stuff* and is part of the c++ standard.